# GCC Runtime Library Exception

Tags: gcc

i want to use use gcc compiler (under GPLv3) in my c++ project and libstdc++ that comes with GCC compiler but my project is closed source . there is an [exception](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gcc-exception.html) of Runtime Library but i don't understand  it very well.and i have read ([GCC Runtime Library Exception FAQ](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gcc-exception-faq.html)). can some one explain this exception and if i used libstdc++ can i make my program closed source ?.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it seems to belong on https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/